# Why wont my 2d array variable take input?

Tags: java

Noob to programming... I need to create a function that receives a 2d array and requests user input to fill both the rows and the columns. The error that shows me is "empty statement" / "not a statement" on the last line.

```
  public static void fillMatrix(int [][] pmatrix) throws IOException {

       int [][] matrix = new int [pmatrix.length][pmatrix.length];
       int i, k; //loop variables
       int rows, columns; 

       for(i = 0; i < pmatrix.length; i++){

           print.println("set the value of the row " + (i + 1));
           rows = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());                   
       }

       for(k = 0; k < pmatrix.length; k++){

           print.println("set the value of the column " + (k + 1));
           colums = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());   

        }

       matrix = {{rows}, {columns}};


    }
```

Comment: You cannot fill a matrix like this. Use a nested loop to read a 2d array.

Comment: What is `read`?

Comment: @Popeye Is the BufferedReader variable: `public static BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

Comment: `colums` and `columns`. Have you check for typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what you do here is reassigning the variables `rows` and `columns` in each iteration. So at the end, you will have one single value per row in your matrix.

Second, you're reassigning the *local* variable `matrix` to be a Matrix, that has two rows and one column. And since it doesn't have anything to do with the parameter `pmatrix`, nothing will happen to it after the method returns.

I assume you want to call that method on an empty 2D-Array and fill it with values from the console. To iterate through a 2D-Array, you will need a nested for-loop and access each index in your matrix individually:

```
public static void fillMatrix(int [][] pmatrix) throws IOException {
    for(i = 0; i < pmatrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < pmatrix[i].length; i++ {
            print.println("set the value of row " + (i + 1) + " in column " + (j + 1));
            pmatrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());    
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to understand in the full context. 
The following code has a main method that creates a matrix of size 3x3, you can change this if you like.
Next, it calls the `fillMatrix` method and then the `printMatrix` method.

`fillMatrix` goes through each row and for each row, it goes through each column. For an entry in the matrix, it reads an integer using `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader` because it is easier to use.

`printMatrix` runs through all the entries and prints them as a table.

Running the program and giving `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` prints

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

The program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Helper {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];
        fillMatrix(matrix);
        printMatrix(matrix);
    }

    public static void fillMatrix(final int[][] matrix) throws IOException {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            final int[] row = matrix[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                final int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
                row[j] = userInput;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printMatrix(final int[][] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            final int[] row = matrix[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(row[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!